# react-native-image-crop-tools aspect ration of an image for a perfect square

Tags: javascript, react-native, image, aspect-ratio

I'm on a react-native project and on an image crop with react-native-image-crop-tools...
To display a perfect square with the size, width of my screen, do you know how to do it?
So far, I have tried a lot of ratios, but without success:

```
style={{ width: Dimensions.get('screen').width, height: Dimensions.get('screen').height }}
          ref={cropViewRef}
          onImageCrop={(res) => console.warn(res)}
          keepAspectRatio
          aspectRatio={{ width: Dimensions.get('screen').width / 9, height: Dimensions.get('screen').height / 12 }}
```

ps: ignore the values ​​here ^^
ps2: i'm on tablet in landscape mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand your question correctly, you should set the width to the width of your screen and the aspect ratio to `{width:1,height:1}`

Comment: thx @RodSar, if I set the width /height to screen width & height and set the ratio
I need a margin at the bottom to add because I have a tool bar at the bottom...
on what value do you think i should add/remove this margin?

Comment: then i suggest that you keep the ratio as 1 to 1, just add a marginBottom or paddingBottom in your style, if the component doesn't respect that margin for some reason, then i guess you can experiment with setting maxHeight too

Comment: yes top it is already much better thx :)